# CreateIfNotExists() does it not create the Tables of the context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I was trying to create a custom initializer in Entity Framework:

```
    public void InitializeDatabase(DataSourceContext context)
    {
        if (context.Database.Exists())
        {
            try
            {
                if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
                {
                    context.Database.Delete();
                    context.Database.Create();

                }
                else
                {
                    context.Database.Create();
                }
            }
```

But I get this error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.SiteSources'.

Which I assume is because even though the database connection is made, the `sitesource` table isn't created. It would've worked otherwise if I just run the initializer `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`.

Comment: Initializer code is executed only when the application is restarted - that means something had caused AppDomain recycling (should be caused by new DLL deployment to bin folder). Try to restart the web server to make sure that application has restarted.

Comment: Oh sorry, what I basically did was point it to a new Testdatabase because I want to try test with modified models. I got the empty TestDatabase but I thought code-first would generate the tables for me when I call the database.Create but it doesnt.